# Sql sever 2008 r2 stored procedure arabic columns name not appear

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I try this sql code

```
    declare @resultSet Nvarchar(4000)

set @resultSet = 'SELECT 
      byng.Quantity * itm.Price N''السعر''

  FROM [Buying] byng
  inner join Item itm on byng.ItemId = itm.Id
  '
 exec(@resultSet)
```

always column name appear in UTF encoding and looks '?????'

Comment: BTW, and unrelated to the question, you don't need dynamic SQL for such a query, normal querying is much better when it fits the bill.

Comment: yeah i'll try to use case ,instead of dynamic sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
declare @ColumnName Nvarchar(4000) = N'السعر'
declare @resultSet NVARCHAR(MAX)


SET @resultSet = N'SELECT byng.Quantity * itm.Price AS ' + @ColumnName
               + N' FROM [Buying] byng
                  inner join Item itm on byng.ItemId = itm.Id'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @resultSet
```

Or the way you have used is just fine too but you need to prefix your Sql statement with `N` you are concatenating a unicode character and not prefixing the sql string with `N` so therefore it is going undetected.

Something like this...

```
DECLARE  @resultSet NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @resultSet = N'SELECT  byng.Quantity * itm.Price AS ''السعر''
                   FROM [Buying] byng
                   inner join Item itm on byng.ItemId = itm.Id'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @resultSet
```

Comment: Not a problem bro glad to help :)